# Ionic open modal in app.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement Web intent and need to show popup when user shared something with my app and want to get some text.

```
    if (window.plugins && window.plugins.webintent) {

        var incomingURL;
        window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT,function(url) {
            incomingURL = url
             var myPopup = messageAlert.saveData(url);

      }, function() {
        incomingURL = false;
      }
  );
```

Here messageAlert is a factory. I want to show a modal or popup where user can input some text and i can use furture.

```
.factory('messageAlert', function ($ionicPopup,$timeout,$ionicModal) {
    return {
      saveData : function(url) {
         // here i tried different scenes. but nothing work out. 
        // i want a form where user can input some data and save 
      }
    }

}
```

Can anybody give me idea

Comment: you said, the user can share something from your app, how about a ngCordova plugin ? much like this ... http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/

Comment: it's not social Sharing.   this is shgaring with my app. when u are not another app. hit share it will show you myapp name . and i need a text box or modal so user can put some text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your problem is not about getting the webintent to work, but simply to display the `$ionicPopup`.

So the main issue I see, is that you inject the `$ionicPopup` within a factory. Since you want to display the popup on a view, you need to inject it in your controller. There you can create a popup like this:

```
$ionicPopup.prompt({
   title: 'Your title text',
   template: 'Please enter your text here',
   inputType: 'text',
   inputPlaceholder: 'Your text here'
 }).then(function(res) {
   // after the user typed something, this result callback will be called
   // res will contain the text which your user entered
 });
```

You can find the corresponding docs with possible settings [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).

Trying to merge this with your code above, I would suggest something like this:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($ionicPopup, messageAlert) {

    this.someFunction = function() {

        if (window.plugins && window.plugins.webintent) {
            var incomingURL;
            window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT,function(url) {
                incomingURL = url;

                // open the text input popup
                var myPopup = $ionicPopup.prompt({
                   title: 'Your title text',
                   template: 'Please enter your text here',
                   inputType: 'text',
                   inputPlaceholder: 'Your text here'
                });

                // after the user typed something, this result callback will be called
                myPopup.then(function(userText) {
                   // userText contains the text which your user entered
                   // now you can save the data with your factory
                   messageAlert.saveData(incomingURL, userText);
                });

            }, function() {
                incomingURL = false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Please note that I did not test the latter code, since I do not understand your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to debug the problem:

1. Does it work when you put a simple `alert('YES THIS WORKS!')` in the `messageAlert.saveData()` factory?
2. Are you sure that the app was invoked with the specified extra? See: https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent#hasextra